# Dynamics CRM : Unable to populate the related child records based on parent ID in active form

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Dynamics 365  - I am new to this , just started exploring to develop a POC and right now struck at below

Have 2 tables requestId  and requestDetails  both have relation based on requestID (1:N) and requirement is to display the child data (request details) once the user selects a requestID.  But after creating the relationship, child data (requestdetails) is not getting displayed in active form.

Appreciate any help / pointers to documentations which covers this scenario.

Tried subgrids but no luck.

Comment: Add some screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Your RequestDetail Entity has lookup field created when you created a relationship with RequestID.

What you need to do is create few Sample records for Requestdeatils using grid from requestid.

On requestid entity add a grid and show related entity which will have a drop down for  requestdetails.

Once you do that and when you work on your record you will be able to create a requestdetails record from requestid of it you have few requestdetails records already created you could simply add them and link them to requestid.